# IIS URL Rewrite main entry site redirect to blue / green entry

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

First, I am not great at writing regular expressions, so I apologize for that.

I am trying to setup IIS to rewrite URLs from one main entry to a secondary blue / green entry site. As part of a multi-tenancy setup users are redirected by US state abbreviations. For now, we will only be looking for the 2 letters after the domain name.  All traffic will be coming in to the main entry site `https://dev.app.com` and redirected to the appreciate state's URL

For example: 
 `http://dev.app.com/ca` or `http://dev.app.com/ny`

By default, users that come into the root of the site `http://dev.app.com` will be automatically redirected to `http://dev.app.com/ca`. CA is our default state.

Each state has its own blue / green entry site. For example: `http://ca.app.entry`. The blue / green entry sites have a reverse proxy rewrite rule to redirect traffic to whatever site is currently running. The blue / green rewrite rule is updated during deployment.

Also, each state has its own API. For example: `http://ca.api.com`. The main entry URL would look like this: `https://dev.app.com/ca/ext` and it would forward traffic to the correct state's API.

I have been trying to setup the rewrite rules to trap the state abbreviation and also look for the `ext` if it exists and forward to the appropriate AI site.

For the default URL I started out by creating a redirect rule that comes before the rewrite rules

```
 <httpRedirect enabled="true">
      <add wildcard="/" destination="/ca" />
 </httpRedirect>
```

The next rule I am trying to trap the state abbreviation:

```
<rule name="StateRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="/([a-z]{2})/$" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{R:1}.app.entry" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Testing the expression I get the proper 2 letter state abbreviation as long as there is nothing after the [state]/. So http://dev.app.com/ca/someOtherqueryString does not produce a match. Going to http://dev.app.com/ca/ does not seem to forward traffic to [state].app.entry/[state]. If I go directly to the state's entry site it works. So, going to ca.app.entry/ca routes to the proper blue / green site. Looking at the logs it doesn't seem to be constructing the the entire URL. I am only seeing the `/[state]/` in the log: `2018-12-27 16:57:25 127.0.0.1 GET /ca/`

For the API site I tried a pattern rule like this `(.*)/ext/(.*)`. The rule comes after the state abbreviation rule, but it is still not routing to the proper state API site.

I could use some help constructing the rules and how they need to be ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following regex will return 2 chars from the end of the string `[a-z]{2}$` if there can be a / after that then it would be like this `[a-z]{2}/?$`

that is for regex as for the rewrite rules it should work but i am not sure exactly how the rewrites work with substitutions so hope this helps